# How to make a bool insert a X in report when true

Tags: c#

```
foreach (SalesInfo sales in this)
{
  if (sales.Senior == true)
    senX = "x";
  if (sales.Veteran == true)
    vetX = "x";
  fileOut.WriteLine("{0:d4} {1,-25} {2,-14} {3,3} {4,3} {5,10:MM/dd/yyyy} {6,10:n} "
                   + "{7,10:n} {8,8:n} {9,6:n} {10,10:n}",
                   sales.ID, sales.Name, sales.City, senX, vetX, sales.PurDate,
                   sales.ProductTotal, sales.DiscountTotal, sales.SalesTax, sales.ShippingCharge,
                   sales.InvoiceTotal);
}
```

So my problem is when the data member for Senior or Veteran is true I need to insert a X into my report.  This inst working so I wondered if anyone knew of a better way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working'? What are you getting as an output?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set `senX` and `vetX` back to `""` after writing the line, so it's empty for the new iteration. Otherwise you'll get exes throughout the report, regardless of the value of the boolean.

Another solution would be to use `(sales.Senior?"X":"")` as an expression in the WriteLine statement, so you don't need the variables at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SalesInfo sales in this)
{
  senX = sales.Senior ? "x" : "";
  vetX = sales.Veteran ? "x" : "";
  fileOut.WriteLine("{0:d4} {1,-25} {2,-14} {3,3} {4,3} {5,10:MM/dd/yyyy} {6,10:n} "
                   + "{7,10:n} {8,8:n} {9,6:n} {10,10:n}",
                   sales.ID, sales.Name, sales.City, senX, vetX, sales.PurDate,
                   sales.ProductTotal, sales.DiscountTotal, sales.SalesTax, sales.ShippingCharge,
                   sales.InvoiceTotal);
}
```

If you use the ternary operator (x ? y : z) in your assignments, it will take care of assigning the "x" and clearing the value to "" each loop iteration.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add in the characters "{" and "}"!

```
if (sales.Senior == true)
{
  senX = "x";
}

if (sales.Veteran == true)
{
  vetX = "x";
}
```

Comment: -1; there is no difference between a single line if statement (as in the O.P.'s code) w/o control braces and with control braces, other than coding standards. They both compile down to the exact same thing.